# Assignment of results from methods using promises

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

Let's say i have the following setup ('method' in this example is an overly simplified version, the real method I'm dealing with has a pretty long promise chain inside):

```
P = require 'bluebird'

something = [ { id: 1, title: 'hello' }, { id: 2, title: 'world' } ]
method = (param) -> P.try -> param * 2
```

I'm trying to assign the results of 'method' to item.newId

```
P.each something, (item) ->
  item.newId = method item.id
.then (result) ->
  console.log result
```

The results of that were not what I expected initially, but it completely makes sense, because method return a promise.

```
[ { id: 1,
    title: 'hello',
    newId:
     { _bitField: 268435456,
       _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
       _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
       _progressHandler0: undefined,
       _promise0: undefined,
       _receiver0: undefined,
       _settledValue: 2 } },
  { id: 2,
    title: 'world',
    newId:
     { _bitField: 268435456,
       _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
       _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
       _progressHandler0: undefined,
       _promise0: undefined,
       _receiver0: undefined,
       _settledValue: 4 } } ]
```

So I've changed the code to look like this:

```
P.each something, (item) ->
  method(item.id).then (i) -> item.newId = i
.then (result) ->
  console.log result
```

This produces the expected results:

```
[ { id: 1, title: 'hello', newId: 2 },
  { id: 2, title: 'world', newId: 4 } ]
```

The question I have is, whether the final solution is the proper way to handle this type of assignment when dealing with promise methods.

Comment: Yes, this is a perfectly viable solution. You could also `P.map`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine. However it's not the only way to do this, you might as well do

```
P.map something, (item) ->
  item.newId = method(item.id);
  P.props item
.then (result) ->
  console.log result
```